# Why does sbt-native-packager generate a hardcoded top-level parent directory in distribution packages?

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-native-packager

For example, in Archives.scala:

```
def makeZip(target: File, name: String, mappings: Seq[(File, String)]): File = {
  ...
  val m2 = mappings map { case (f, p) => f -> (name +"/"+p) }

def makeTarball(compressor: File => File, ext: String)(target: File, name: String, mappings: Seq[(File, String)]): File = {
  ...
  val m2 = mappings map { case (f, p) => f -> (rdir / name / p) }
```

I'm trying to understand the reason why this additional directory "name" must be hardcoded inside these functions. In the old distribution packages (prior to sbt-native-packager), I don't believe this extra directory level was there. We're trying to use sbt-native-packager to create some distribution zip/tgz's which do not have this, and for the moment have copied and hacked the code inside Archives.scala so that the mappings: Seq[(File, String)] correspond directly to the structure inside the distribution packages rather than with having the additional "name" directory, but obviously this is not ideal. Perhaps someone familiar with this domain could shed some light on this? (@jsuereth, I'm looking at you :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more due to expections on my end than anything.  You should open a ticket to enhance the project so this behavior is configurable via a flag.

Comment: Well, I propose that to preserve generality of these functions, rather than configuring this via a flag, hardcoding of the top-level 'name' directory should just be completely dropped altogether. I claim that whoever is invoking this function would find it trivial to add the 'name' to the beginning of all the mappings if s/he sees fit. Do you agree?

Comment: But just out of curiosity, what expectations are you referring to? As pointed out above, the pre-(sbt-native-packager) packaging system did not include these top-level 'name' directories, so I'm not sure what might be the purpose of that.

Comment: Yeah, these are expectations from, e.g. downloading a tar.gz. file of some OSS linux-y software.  Almost any distribution of software you download is in a named directory on the zip, so we did it this way to be convenient.

These are not expectations from the play community.  I believe the native-packager tries to make JVM community more conformant with the outside world.  

That said, this should totally be configurable.  If you open a bug, I'll get to it when I can.  Sorry if it caused confusion/issues.